# How to update subtype attribute values in oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, object-relational-model

How to update column value of a subtype?

Code like this can't access the grade attribute of student:

```
update persons set grade = 'graduated';
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE person (
    name varchar2(20),
    age number,
    address varchar2(20)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE student UNDER person (
    grade varchar2(20)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TABLE persons OF person;

INSERT INTO persons VALUES (student('Jon', 'undergraduate'));
```

How I change student grade to 'graduated'?

Comment: your person do not have an attribut `grade`

Comment: if you query using:
select treat(value(s) as student) from persons s;

you can see that it have the attribute grade;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a answer to my problem. 
This is the code to update subtype attributes:

```
DECLARE
    s student;

BEGIN
    select treat(value(p) as student) into s from persons p where name = 'Jon';
    s.grade = 'graduated';
    update persons p set value(p) = s where name = 'Jon';
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

that should work

```
update persons s set VALUE(s) = student(treat(value(s) as student).name, 'graduated');
```

Comment: if i have more columns in person?

Comment: more columns in person to pass inside student constructor